# show one view controller on other view controller as a subview(popoverController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uipopovercontroller

hello i want to present a controller on a main view Controller with popover functionality can anyone me out this ??
i have already tried this below code but it is comin on all view, i want it in small size at the center of view.
here is the code below

```
Login *popoverController = [[Login alloc] init];
popoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view; //The view containing the anchor rectangle for the popover.
popoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(384, 40, 40, 40); //The rectangle in the specified view in which to anchor the popover.
[self presentViewController:popoverController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Container View. Add a container view to your parent view and add other view controllers in your container view.

```
 self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let popOverView = self.popoverController.popoverPresentationController
            popOverView!.delegate = self
            if popOverView!.sourceView == nil
            {
                popOverView!.sourceView = self.view
                self.popoverController.superView = self

            }
            popOverView!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(“X-Define”, ““Y-Define”, “Width”, “Height”)
            popOverView!.passthroughViews = [self.view] 

            self.presentViewController(self.popoverController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it help you...

in .m file

Suppose your storyboard segue identifier name is `showPopover`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"showPopover"]) {

        UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(180,130);


        UIPopoverPresentationController *ppc = dvc.popoverPresentationController;
        if (ppc) {
            ppc.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Add this also:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {

    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```